# dynamically evaluating javascript expressions in winrt/xaml/c# applications

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Is there a way of evaluating javascript expressions, which are loaded from an external source at runtime, in a winrt application written in XAML and c#?

**Consider the following pseudo-code:**

```
String expression = File.ReadAll(somefile);

String result = AnyJavascriptEngineAvailableUnderWinRT.Evaluate(expression);
```

before winrt, we have been using Microsoft.JScript engine. 
Now, with winrt, we have been trying Jint, which led to runtime exception "The API 'System.Type.ReflectionOnlyGetType(System.String, Boolean, Boolean)' cannot be used on the current platform. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248273 for more information."

To be honest, I would prefer addressing the built-in javascript engine coming with winrt, but I would also accept "AnyJavascriptEngineAvailableUnderWinRT", if it allows expressions to be evaluated dynamically.

Comment: Try jurassic.codeplex.com. It works on silverlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily by tapping into IE directly through the `WebView`.

Like this:

```
var js = "whatever you want";
var webView = new WebView();
var result = webView.InvokeScript("eval", new[] { js });
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Some errors/not so good practices in the third line, use this: await 
webview.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] {js});